# Is it possible for multiple backgrounds to behave like <div>'s?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm designing a site that requires multiple backgrounds (which are not grouped in a photo, by the way) It's like you have to assemble it to achieve the layout.

What I want to do is something like this:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
.multiple-backgrounds {
  background-image: 
    url('/backgrounds/bg-1.jpg'),
    url('/backgrounds/bg-2.jpg'), 
    url('/backgrounds/bg-3.jpg');

  background-repeat: 
    no-repeat, 
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat;

  background-size: 
    100% 810px, 
    100%,
    cover;

  background-position: 
    top, 
    top,
    top;

  background-color: #123 /* fallback */;
}
```

But the output just keeps on stacking, which is right. But is there a workaround to make it like the sample screenshot above?

Comment: Any reason that you are only limited  to 1 div?

Comment: Make the backgrounds only 1/3 of the height each and then position them top/middle/bottom...No?

Comment: if you know the image sizes (or you will set it), yes. If not, no.

Comment: @Jackyef actually, I'm not limiting myself to 1 div. I just wanted to try if it's possible to do it in one div. If my solution is impractical, you may suggest a workaround :)

Comment: @Paulie_D, I'm making it a whole page background, so it's continuous. The background will be from top to bottom of the page.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, hmm, I'll try that now!

Comment: Not sure why thats an issue...33% of the page height should work regardless of the page height or viewport.

Comment: @Paulie_D ahhhh. Sorry, I didn't get your answer earlier. Now I get it, will try this one after the one I'm working on right now :D

Comment: It finally worked guys! Thank you for the time in answering my question. I went with @TemaniAfif's solution. :D